# md5 at URL, but extract $id (CodeIgniter)

Tags: codeigniter, url, md5

Anyone please can help me? I'm using CodeIgniter. My problem is, i need to header a md5 url as my $pr_id, but it actually extract the the $pr_id for the next step. Here's my code :

```
   if ($res) {
        $id = $this -> model_prcsys -> get_max ();
        $pr_id = $id [0] -> pr_id;
        $md = md5($pr_id);
        header ('location:'.base_url()."prcsys/next_step_pr/$md");
    }
```

The problem is, i need to URL those $md, but I'll use the $pr_id for the next step. Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Not a codeigniter user here, but md5 is a one way hash;

You should look into base64_encode() and base64_decode()

To encode :

```
$md = base64_encode($pr_id);
```

To decode :

```
$pr_id = base64_decode($md);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, dude. Now I know that md5 can't be vice versa. But it stil can't solve my problem ...

Comment: @ArdeeNetGeek maybe you can share the code on the next step, and we can look at it together?